# iOS: Resize all UILabel Fonts to match

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uilabel, autoresize

I have a several UILabels that are filled with text.

All of the fonts within the UILabels are set to autoshrink.

If one of the UILabels contains too much text (and must be automatically resized), how do I then change the remaining UILabels fonts sizes to match the one that has been resized?

At the end of my code, I have used the following:

```
 if (self.label.font.pointSize < 16){

        labelTwo.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Noteworthy-Bold" size:self.label.font.pointSize];
```

My default font size is 16, so I am checking to see if the font size has been reduced.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not at my Mac at the moment, so I can't write the actual code for you, but I can psuedo it for you so you know which direction to head.

```
Create a variable to store the smallest font size.
Foreach for each UILabel in the view.
Get the font size.
Check the font size against the smallest known so far.
    If the font size is smaller than the smallest known, save it.
    Else, disregard.
After all UILabels in view have been checked go back through them, and set the font size to that of the saved value
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how i achieved it

```
CGFloat fontSize = self.label1.font.pointSize;
CGFloat fontSize1 = self.label2.font.pointSize;
CGFloat fontSize2 = self.label3.font.pointSize;
NSArray *numbers = @[[NSNumber numberWithFloat:fontSize],[NSNumber numberWithFloat:fontSize1],[NSNumber numberWithFloat:fontSize2]];
float xmax = -MAXFLOAT;
float xmin = MAXFLOAT;
for (NSNumber *num in numbers) {
    float x = num.floatValue;
    if (x < xmin) xmin = x;
    if (x > xmax) xmax = x;
    NSLog(@"lowest number = %f",xmin);
```